# How to populate dimensions with no matching columns?

Tags: database-design, ssis, star-schema

I'm working on a project for school and I'm new to the database design so I would appreciate any advice to learn the best practices.

I was giving a data source for a bank and my assignment is to create OLTP then DW.
My OLTP is as follows

[image]

now I'm trying to populate these to the dimension tables but I was told that having the `LoanNumber` like this is redundant and also I can't have this column in all of the fact and dim tables for the next step.
My questions are:

1. As far as I know, is that I need a matching column to do look up to or use the `MERGE` statement on to move the data to the DW. So what should I do in this case?
2. If I take off the `LoanNumber` column how would I join between these tables? should I replace it with and ID columns for each table, would that be a good thing?

the dim tables that I have
[image]
the fact tables
[image]

Comment: What dimensions are you trying to build?

Comment: @billinkc I updated the post to include how I have the dim and fact tables so far

Comment: The design of an OLTP system is very different from a data warehouse. Your current dimension tables are just your OLTP tables with a surrogate key and some auditing "stuff" Your fact tables aren't great (Loan number shouldn't be in there as you're not aggregating or slicing by it - directly at least. The loan_status column in the loan table should be pulled out into either its own dimension or a "junk dimension" Issue_d should be using the same shared date table that drives datekey. `Acc_now_delinq` smells like it's an attribute of the loan and should be on that table